# My chatterbot will import but won't run because of "module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'", why is this?

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

I downloaded chatterbot and can import it into python but as soon as I try to use it, it prints a series of errors, why is this and how can I fix it?

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
bot = ChatBot('chatbot')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    bot = ChatBot('chatbot')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 54, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 22, in __init__
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 264, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```